Nautilus is not opening and close immediately
When I update my Ubuntu from 16 lts to 20 lts the all other file run normally ,but my Nautilus file does not open . Even I try to open via terminal it open up and closed suddenly.i see method in ask Ubuntu and youtube, but wouldn't help . It shows when I open via terminal segmentation fault :core dumped . How can I recover the files file manager and my system.

Does Files open normally without seg faulting if you run sudo apt purge nautilus && sudo apt install nautilus && nautilus ? Does thunar open normally if you run sudo apt  install thunar and launch Thunar file manager?

There is no upgrade path from Ubuntu Core 16 to Ubuntu Core 20 (or Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) except via the intermediate 18/18.04 which you make no mention of. Your forced & unsupported upgrade path maybe the cause; so being specific as to what you're using & changes you made maybe helpful, in allowing us to help you.
